# How to store artifact file for Gitlab CI scheduled pipelines

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I see that artifacts are belongs to pipeline. Is there any way to store artifacts(json file) for forever and mount into Gitlab pipline?

I need to run scheduled and automated updates of K8s. For that I'm store upgrade status in json file, this json file used/updated by other scheduled automated update. If artifacts belongs to pipeline, I have keep track of pipline numbers.

So is there any easy way to store data in artifact and get mounted while pipeline is running for update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache` solves my problem

```
aks-baseline-k8s-update:
  stage: k8s-update
  image: "toolbox:master"

  script:
    - update.sh
  cache:
    key: upgrade-history
    paths:
      - upgrade-history.json
  only:
    refs:
      - schedules
    variables:
      - $SCHEDULE_TYPE == "aks-k8s"
```