# how to pass git commit message from parent to child pipeline in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a commit message stored in /tmp/message file in parent's pipeline and I would like to send the contents of this file to the child pipeline in Gitlab. Can someone help me how I can do this using yml pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to [use a cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-cache-is-different-from-artifacts) (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71238217/6309)), or rather [an artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38140996/6309)), in order to store that message content in a file.

The idea is to share a file (artifact) or key/value (cache) between jobs.